# How can i put the path of an image in a variable and use it with imread()

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

i want to select an image and save the path in a variable. Then I want to use this variable to display the image. For this I have used the following code:

```
def open_dialog_box(self):
        filename, _ = np.asarray(QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Select Multi File', 'default', 'All Files (*)'))
        for name in filename:
            #import pic
            pic = cv2.imread(name, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH) #This doesn't works
            **pic = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Image_name", cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)** #This works
            cv2.imshow("Window", pic)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Fenster()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The bold line works. But I don't want to enter the whole path every time. I want the path to be automatically stored in a variable and then used to display the image. Is there a method to use a variable instead of typing the whole path ?

Comment: remove `np.asarray`, is unnecessary.

Comment: I have done that, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: what is the output of `print(name)`?

Comment: The output is something like "C:/Users/Image_name.png. I think the problem ist, when i safe the path in a variable, it safe with "/" and not with "\\". But dont know how to fix it.

Comment: change to `pic = cv2.imread(os.path.abspath(name), cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)`

Comment: Thank you, now I get the path with "\" like: "C:\Users\Image_name.png. 

But Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Currently it only works if I type it in manually with "//".

Comment: If i use: `pic = cv2.imread(r "C:\Users\Image_name.png", cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)` it works. But its only possible if i write the path manualy. Theres no solution like: `pic = r name, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this to see if it is working for you:

```
import cv2
import os.path
xp2 = os.path.abspath("")
#xp2 is having the path of the image, currently it is having pwd.
#print(xp2)
xp3 = xp2+"\screenshot.png"
#xp3 is the new variable with ur file name as to be used
img_1 = cv2.imread(xp3)
print(img_1)
```

on printing the img_1 I get the o/p of image.
Now you can use this path as per your need in your program.